# Ionic | Como pongo un icono a la izquierda de ion-label?

Tags: ionic, angular, cordova

Alguien me puede ayudar por favor a como poner un ion-icon en un ion-label en Ionic? 
Lo probé así:

```
<ion-item color="quest">

    <ion-label floating
               ion-left>Correo Electronico</ion-label>
    <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
    <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

Asi lo probe y no me funciono, si me pueden ayudar por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yo lo hago así:

```
   <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>
      <ion-icon name="mail" item-start class="text-primary"></ion-icon>
      Email
    </ion-label>
    <ion-input type="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

O se te falta poner ion-icon dentro de ion-label y ademas que ion-icon tenga la propiedad item-start